# how do you put wordpress post images into list items

Tags: wordpress

I want to take the images in my wordpress single page post and put them in a list order.  The purpose is to then create a custom slider off of that list.

or if someone knows a good image slider for wordpress that has dynamic heights let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there are plenty of sliders either the wordpress plugin or jquery plugin. My recommendation is the jquery plugin named Coda slider where it can be modified to be used even on the div